Mapping from Logged Data
I'm a beginner in ros and mapping. I want to use gmapping from a *.bag file, but some problems encountered. There are more details below:
This is the info of the bag file:
types:       nav_msgs/Odometry         [cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]
             sensor_msgs/Imu           [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan     [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
             sensor_msgs/MagneticField [2f3b0b43eed0c9501de0fa3ff89a45aa]
topics:      /driver/encoder    4758 msgs    : nav_msgs/Odometry        
             /driver/eul       28635 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu          
             /driver/imu       28469 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu          
             /driver/mag       28469 msgs    : sensor_msgs/MagneticField
             /driver/scan       1017 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan


I try to follow the official instructions, but unfortunately, it have not topic /tf, which is gmapping required. So i try to use following launch commands to publish a /tf topic:
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_tf_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint laser_link 10" />

Nothing changed, many warnings are showing out:
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://peterptroc:43599/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES
  /
    rviz (rviz/rviz)
    static_tf_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[static_tf_broadcaster-1]: started with pid [23121]
process[rviz-2]: started with pid [23122]
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[ INFO] [1732438906.355303792]: rviz version 1.14.20
[ INFO] [1732438906.355412411]: compiled against Qt version 5.15.3
[ INFO] [1732438906.355425826]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1732438906.374511671]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[ INFO] [1732438906.556814962]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1732438906.557003949]: OpenGL device: GFX1103_R1 (gfx1103_r1, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.57, 6.8.0-49-generic)
[ INFO] [1732438906.557026560]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6) limited to GLSL 1.4 on Mesa system.
[ WARN] [1732438916.611783829, 124.682856923]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame odom (parent map) at time 124.732023 according to authority unknown_publisher
[ WARN] [1732438916.662386861, 124.733240642]: Detected jump back in time of 0.00938928s. Clearing TF buffer.
...
[ WARN] [1732438946.512864563, 154.582826639]: Detected jump back in time of 0.00952123s. Clearing TF buffer.
[ WARN] [1732438946.553210118, 154.623216685]: Detected jump back in time of 0.00952406s. Clearing TF buffer.
[ WARN] [1732438946.633380993, 154.703968867]: Detected jump back in time of 0.00953474s. Clearing TF buffer.

Addtionally, I can provide the message of this bag:
this is msg from laser:
# =======================================
# topic:           /driver/scan
# msg_count:       1
# timestamp (sec): 1726872768.870787621
# - - -
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 1726872768
    nsecs: 708397871
  frame_id: "laser_link"
angle_min: 0.0
angle_max: 6.2831854820251465
angle_increment: 0.006239508744329214
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.0
range_min: 0.0
range_max: 10.0
ranges: [...]
intensities: [...]

and this is msg from encoder, may be it's useful, but idk how to use it.(actually only pose-pose-position-x is changing during this bag)
# =======================================
# topic:           /driver/encoder
# msg_count:       1
# timestamp (sec): 1726872768.600995064
# - - -
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 1726872768
    nsecs: 430500957
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 0.0
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]

I use this file to launch:
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_tf_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint laser_link 10" />

  <include file="$(find gmapping)/launch/slam_gmapping_pr2.launch">
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/driver/scan"/>
    <arg name="base_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <arg name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  </include>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" output="screen"/>
</launch>

and the gmapping launch file:
<launch>
  <arg name="scan_topic"  default="/driver/scan" />
  <arg name="base_frame"  default="base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame"  default="odom"/>

  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)"/>   
<param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)"/>   
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="1.0"/>        
    <param name="maxUrange" value="20.0"/>                
    <param name="maxRange" value="25.0"/>                 
    <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
    <param name="minimumScore" value="200"/>
    <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.436"/>
    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/>
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="particles" value="80"/>
    <param name="xmin" value="-25.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-25.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="25.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="25.0"/>

    <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
  </node>
</launch>

so my problem is: how can i make my gmapping working properly?
any suggestions are  appreciated, thanks!

The gmapping node takes the Transform Frame odom -> base_footprint as input.
If you create a ros node that subscribes to /odom and re-publishes the data in the correct type of message to /tf, gmapping might begin to work (caveat: I've never tried to do it this way.)
Also make sure you're using the original timestamps when you play the bag file.
